# Creating custom analyzer in C# with mandatory string variable in all files

Tags: c#, .net-core, analyzer

I am trying to create a custom analyzer in C# which will ensure that we will have a string variable always declared in a class file

I have gone through a few tutorials like [Building a Code Analyzer for .NET](https://timheuer.com/blog/building-a-code-analyzer-for-net/).

Is this even possible to enforce? I am trying to build my own Test Impact Analysis tools based on feature tags in spec flow. This variable will enforce declaration of my SpecFlow annotations.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a string variable always declared in a class file"? That each class contains any - or a specific? - field - or property? - of type string?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.